# How to get difference between 2 dates (Z format) in milliseconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Well I'm trying to get the difference between two dates in `Seconds.MilliSeconds`  The dates are in Zulu format

I have tried these two approaches doesn't work out for me

```
ms1=$(date -d '2022-04-22T03:47:56.744551446Z' +%N)
ms2=$(date -d '2022-04-22T03:47:57.095419744Z' +%N)
msdiff=$((ms1 - ms2))
echo "$msdiff"
```

```
$ dateutils.ddiff  2022-04-22T03:47:56.744551446Z 2022-04-22T03:47:57.095419744Z -f '%N'
0s
```

Is there any better way to get the difference in `Seconds.MilliSeconds` In linux for `Z` format time zones

Comment: What do you man by "better"? From the program structure, your solution looks clean to me. Aree you worried about performance? I.e. do you have to calculate it often in a loop?

Comment: @user1934428 None of the Above is giving the difference Seconds.MilliSeconds

Comment: In this case, your problem is not so much finding the difference, but converting a number of the form  _Seconds.MilliSeconds_  into ms, since you want to have the result of the calculation as an integer expressing the miliseconds - is this correct? In this case, you better make this clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Suggesting

```
ms1=$(date -d '2022-04-22T03:47:56.744551446Z' +%s.%N)
ms2=$(date -d '2022-04-22T03:47:57.095419744Z' +%s.%N)
msdiff=$(awk "BEGIN{print $ms2 - $ms1}")
echo "msdiff=$msdiff"
```

#### Output:

```
msdiff=0.350868
```

Comment: This yields the result as a fractional number of _seconds_. The OP stated that he wanted to have the difference expressed in miliseconds. You would have to multiply your difference by 1000 to achieve this.